# Doctrine select between two coords

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to merge?

```
$collection = $this->em->getRepository('User')->createQueryBuilder('u');
$collection = $collection->where('u.user IN (:followers)');
```

and

```
 $collection->addSelect(
     '(3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . 47.2146561 . '))' .
     '* cos(radians(p.latitude))' .
     '* cos(radians(p.longitude)' .
     '- radians(' . 38.920443 . '))' .
     '+ sin(radians(' . 47.2146561 . '))' .
     '* sin(radians(p.latitude)))) as distance' )->where('p.user = :user');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you want to do, but my guess is you want to join a position table and add a select like follows:

```
$collection = $this->em->getRepository('User')->createQueryBuilder('u');
$collection->join('u.position', 'p')
           ->where('u.user IN (:followers)')
           ->addSelect(
        '(3959 * acos(cos(radians('.47.2146561.')) * cos(radians(p.latitude)) * cos(radians(p.longitude) - radians('.38.920443.')) + sin(radians('.47.2146561.')) * sin(radians(p.latitude)))) as distance'
    )
```

I hope this helps.

However There is still something I could not understand in your code. Why do you use concatenation with hard coded values?
If the aim is to have variables instead, then you made the right choice.

Please provide a bit more information the next time you ask (like the `position` table)

Comment: Thx for reply.

Hardcoded values for tests :)

Work good, but return a multidimensional array i want array of objects

Comment: oh! I found a solution!

change as distance to as hidden distance.

Thx!!